# Show listing of all public functions in sidebar for Sphinx documentation

Tags: python, python-sphinx

How would I go about adding a bulleted list of 'public' functions to the sidebar of a project documented with Sphinx?

For example, assume I have a module, api.py, with the following functions:

- function1()
- function2()
- function3()

I would like to have a bulleted list of links to function1, function2, and function3 in the sidebar of the documentation.  These links would link to the page for this function that is documented with `:automodule: api`.  So, each sidebar link would just link to the autodoc'ed information on that function.

I've tried using the built-in `autosummary` extension and the `fulltoc` extension, but I couldn't get them to do this with the random assortment of configuration options I tried.

I'm thinking this might require making a custom sidebar.html template.  However, how would I get the listing of all the functions of in the module in the Jinja template?

Honestly, I wouldn't mind just hard-coding a custom template where I had to manually list out the function and the links, but I can't figure out how to set the `href` on each item to point directly to that functions autodoc'ed information.